# Updating records with Factory Girl factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Using RSpec and Factory Girl, I create a record that when created, has associated 'hours' records automatically created in after_create.

But I want to test with the non-default hours, preferably ones I define in factory girl factories. Here's what I'm thinking I'd like to do:

```
  before (:all) do
    @business = Factory(:business_one)
    # when that business is saved, a set of default hours is automatically saved as well
    # how would I now update the hours with fixtures?
    # so, ideally something like:
    @business.hours[0] << Factory(:day_one)
    @business.hours[1] << Factory(:day_two)
    ...etc...
  end
```

Is this doable somehow or do I need to approach this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
@business = Factory(:business_one)

# clear associations so it's in a known state
@business.hours.clear

@business.hours << Factory(:day_one)
@business.hours << Factory(:day_two)
```

They will still be inserted and saved in the order in which you push in the new association.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create an alternate factory:

```
Factory.define :business_with_altnernate_hours, :parent => :business_one do
  after_create do |business|
    business.hours.clear
    Factory.create(:day_one, :business => business)
    Factory.create(:day_two, :business => business)
  end
end
```